# Doing a download with easywebdav results in bad files

Tags: python, python-3.x, webdav

I have a small program I created to download image files form a FlashAir webdav enabled SD Card.  This works fine with Powershell but trying a Python implementation.

I have it working where easywebdav can download the file but the resulting size is 22Kb which is wrong and windows does not recognize them as a valid file.

I have applied a basestring fix to the client.py for handling Python 3.x instead of 2.x found here [How to overcome Python 3.4 NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130644/how-to-overcome-python-3-4-nameerror-name-basestring-is-not-defined).

I'm on Python 3.5.1.

```
import easywebdav
urlFlashAir = 'http://flashair'
imgLocation = '/DCIM/101MSDCF'
destLocation = 'c:\\test3\\'
remoteDirName = ''
webDavConnection = easywebdav.connect('flashair', '', '')
lsOutput = webDavConnection.ls(imgLocation)
for i in lsOutput:
    if i.size == 0:
        remoteDirName = i.name
    if i.size > 0:
        filename = (i.name).replace(remoteDirName,'')
        print(i.name)
        print(remoteDirName)
        print(filename)
        webDavConnection.download(imgLocation, destLocation + filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected the 22KB article with notepad++ and found that it was a web page for the flashair card.  Upon investigation of the code and documentation I found I was not referencing the remote filename just the location.  Once I fixed the code to append a forward slash and a filename.  Now properly downloads the file.